# Matlab: Is there a way to simplify the command to create dataset arrays for large numbers of variables?

Tags: arrays, matlab, dataset

I want to create a dataset array from several structures like that:

```
data=dataset(S(1,1).gen_bin, S(1,2).gen_bin, S(1,3).gen_bin, S(1,4).gen_bin)
```

For my current problem I need to address up to 30 variables like that. My question would be if there is a way to effectively shorten this command like:

```
data=dataset(S(1,1).gen_bin, S(1,2).gen_bin, ... S(1,30).gen_bin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `dataset` is a function that you are passing your 30 pieces of data to, you can [return data from the structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5pf-1) `S` in the form of a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html) and pass it directly to the function like so:

```
data = dataset(S(1,1:30).gen_bin);
```

If `S` is a structure array with only 30 elements, then you can make it even simpler:

```
data = dataset(S.gen_bin);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I thought I've tried something close to this before but I must have done something wrong.

Comment: I also have a variable x with all 30 variable names in it. Can I use this to replace the generic Var1 - Var30?

Comment: @Mike: It looks like I ended up addressing your extra question in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966628/matlab-question-regarding-dataset). You can adapt that answer to the above problem by collecting your structure elements in a cell array like `varData = {S.gen_bin}.';`.